# Change of selected row in Table for macOS

Tags: macos, swiftui, core-data

I use Table in my CoreData app for macOS

```
@FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)]) private var categories: FetchedResults<Categories>
@State private var selectedCategoryID: Categories.ID?
```

and I'm wondering how I could catch change of selected row. If I try .onChange() as shown below then code can't be compiled due to error "Cannot call value of non-function type 'Categories.ID?' (aka 'Optional<Optional>')"

```
Table(categories, selection: $selectedCategoryID) {
    TableColumn("Name", value \.name!)
    TableColumn("Type", value: \.type!)
}.onChange(of: selectedCategoryID {
    print("Selected row changed.")
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: You have forgotten the closing bracket `)` in `.onChange(of: selectedCategoryID`, change it to `.onChange(of: selectedCategoryID)`

Comment: Yes, that's true but it doesn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the root cause .onChange() must looks like

```
.onChange(of: selectedCategoryID) { selected in
    print("Selected row is \(selected)")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`onChange` is ["to trigger a side effect"](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/SwiftUI/View/onChange(of:perform:)), e.g. something unrelated. If you want to update a related value, then a trick is to move it into a struct with some logic, e.g.

```
struct TableConfig {
    var selectedCategoryID: CategoryID? {
        didSet {
            counter++
        }
    }
    var counter = 0

    mutating func reset() {
        selectedCategoryID = nil
        counter = 0
    }
}
...
@State var config = TableConfig()
...
Table(categories, selection: $config.selectedCategoryID)
```